# Error: Unknown component apex:map - Account.BillingStreet

Tags: visualforce, account

I'm creating a new page and when I try to save the page, I'm getting the error message on this line.... `<apex:map....` the error is not clear and I have no idea what is causing this error.

`{!Account.BillingStreet},{!Account.BillingCity},{!Account.BillingState}">`

> Error: Unknown component apex:map in mymap at line 13 column 141

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

  <!-- This page must be accessed with an Account Id in the URL. For example: 
       https://<salesforceInstance>/apex/NearbyContacts?id=001D000000JRBet ->

  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contacts For {! Account.Name }">

     <apex:dataList value="{! Account.Contacts }" var="contact">
       <apex:outputText value="{! contact.Name }" />
     </apex:dataList> 

  <apex:map width="600px" height="400px" mapType="roadmap" center="{!Account.BillingStreet},{!Account.BillingCity},{!Account.BillingState}">    
    <apex:repeat value="{! Account.Contacts }" var="contact">
    <apex:mapMarker title="{! contact.Name }"
       position="{!contact.MailingStreet},{!contact.MailingCity},{!contact.MailingState}"
    />
    </apex:repeat>

  </apex:map>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Make sure your API version on the VF page is set to v32.0 or higher

Comment: I have set API version 34.0

Comment: You running this page in Developer Edition or in any Sandbox?

Comment: developer edition

Comment: Its not supported in Developer Edition. Check this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<apex:map>` components are not supported in Developer Edition. So you should be trying to run this in Sandbox of supported Production org(Enterprise, Unlimited, etc)

Please refer the [documention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps.htm)

Comment: 1+ yep, you are correct