# Unknown component apex:map in FindNearbyControllerVFPage at line 41 column 52

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing a code from the link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps_example.htm. I have the below code

```
<apex:page controller="FindNearbyController" docType="html-5.0" >

    <!-- JavaScript to get the user's current location, and pre-fill
         the currentPosition form field. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get location, fill in search field
        function setUserLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(loc){
                    var latlon = loc.coords.latitude + "," + loc.coords.longitude;
                    var el = document.querySelector("input.currentPosition");
                    el.value = latlon;
                });
            }
        }
        // Only set the user location once the page is ready
        var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
                clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
                setUserLocation();
            }
        }, 10);
    </script>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <!-- Form field to send currentPosition in request. You can make it
             an <apex:inputHidden> field to hide it. -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:form >
                <apex:outputLabel for="currentPosition">Find Nearby</apex:outputLabel> 
                <apex:input size="30" 
                     html-placeholder="Attempting to obtain your position..."
                     id="currentPosition" styleClass="currentPosition" 
                     value="{!currentPosition}" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!findNearby}" value="Go!"/>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <!-- Map of the results -->
        <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!resultsAvailable}" title="Locations">
            <apex:map width="600px" height="400px">
                <apex:repeat value="{!locations}" var="pos">
                    <apex:mapMarker position="{!pos}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:map>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

In my developer console, code dont know what is `<apex:map`. Could you please let me know what is the issue ?

The error message,

```
Unknown component apex:map in FindNearbyControllerVFPage at line 41 column 52
```

---

As per the link : [Error: Unknown component apex:map - Account.BillingStreet](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90005/error-unknown-component-apexmap-account-billingstreet) .

`<apex:map>` components are not supported in **Developer Edition**. So you should be trying to run this in Sandbox of supported Production org (Enterprise, Unlimited, etc).

**Why there is a restriction of using the API ?** How developer will developed the code ?

Comment: What API Version are you using?

Comment: API version is 40